# which is the table in mysql database to store chat conversations in ejabberd 17.07?

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, ejabberd-module

i have configured ejabberd 17.07 by source and enable mysql.i have made changes in yml file to for using mysql as its databse. now i want to know which is the table in mysql database to store chat conversations in ejabberd ? do i need to add any module or any table for that ? if yes then how can i achieve that? there is a file 'ejabberd.yml'. i can see some modules on admin panel and i also configured the mysql schema for ejabberd which imports some tables.but i am unable to get the table where all chat conversation is stored? i can see a table called offline_messages. there is a table named "users" where i am able get all the registered users.so i think mysql set up is done properly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

mod_mam module will log all messages to db. Its part of 17.07 and you just need to enable in YML file.
Use the following configuration.
**mod_mam: 
    db_type: sql
    default: always**

This will log all one to one messages to **archive** table.
Also you need to create user with 'ejabberd' in mysql(root user will not work). Only then everything will be logged.

Comment: thanks.i have enabled the mam module.and created a user for mysql also. but now i am unable to register a user through my android app which using smack 4.2.i have posted a different question for that if you know how will it get resolve than please post your answer there. the link to question is:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294682/i-am-getting-a-error-when-trying-to-register-a-user-using-smack-api4-2-on-andr