# i am getting a error when trying to register a user using smack api(4.2) on android device on ejabberd (17.07)

Tags: mysql, xmpp, ejabberd, smack, mnesia

I tried to find the reason of the error but cannot found it. If anyone can suggest a way it will be highly appreciated.

Earlier I was using ejabberd version 2.1 with default mnesia, which was working fine. I was able to register users from the android app.

But now when I installed new ejabberd 17.07 with mysql, it gave me error as follow:

```
Connection XMPPTCPConnection[not-authenticated] (5) closed with error
org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException$StreamErrorException: not-authorized You can read more about the meaning of this stream error at http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6120.html#streams-error-conditions

at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1046)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:980)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:996)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 E/ExceptionException: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException: The connection XMPPTCPConnection[not-authenticated] (5) is no longer connected while waiting for response with StanzaIdFilter: id=jq6OD-18
```

Answer (score 1):

its because the user or ip doesn't have the privilege to register new user.You need to do few things for that.
Enable mod_register

**mod_register:
    access_from: all
access: register**

. Make sure your ip blocking is not enabled.Also check **access_rules** that   **register:
    - allow**

is not commented.